# tested sql query not working in vb.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

i am trying to setup auto complete on 2 columns of a DataGridView populated from an sql Server 2008 r2 database. i have tested working a previous version of this code until a NULL value was passed into the database. the query worked fine as

> "SELECT DISTINCT " & Column & " FROM dbo.Purchases"

i tested my new Query in "SQL Server Management Studio" and got the results i was expecting, the same as before minus the Null, but when i put the new query into the code i get an Exception.

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'NULL'.

```
Private Function fillACList(Column As String) As AutoCompleteStringCollection
    Dim temp As AutoCompleteStringCollection
    temp = New AutoCompleteStringCollection
    Using acConn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection("Data Source=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,xxxx;Trusted_Connection=Yes;database=Purchasing_DB")
        Try
            acConn.Open()
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString() & " FillACList")
        End Try
        Using cbCommand As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT " & Column & " FROM dbo.Purchases WHERE " & Column & " IS NOT NULL", acConn)
            Dim reader As SqlDataReader = cbCommand.ExecuteReader()
            While reader.Read()
                If reader.HasRows Then
                    Try
                        Dim input As String
                        input = reader.GetString(0)
                        temp.Add(input)
                    Catch ex As Exception
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString() & " CheckDB")
                    End Try
                End If
            End While
            If (acConn.State = ConnectionState.Open) Then
                acConn.Close()
            End If
        End Using
    End Using
    Return temp
End Function
```

Connection String Redacted for security purposes.

Comment: at which line this error occurs ? may be your column is itself passing as null

Comment: Security perspective this code is not correct. You should manage this by either stored procedure or parametrized sql statement. Inline sql statement do not prevent sql injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you verify that the past parameter column isnot nothing? Since you are using "&" vb.net might not show an error. Use "+" instead, because "&" does a lot of conversion.

Comment: thanks, I need to remember the differences between + and &, and the consequences of one over the other.

Answer (score 0):

You should check what is the actual query in `SqlCommand` and find the issue there.